# No Build Command Defined error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I press CMD+SHIFT+B in Visual Studio Code (to compile typescript to javascript) I get the following error:

```
No build task defined. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand' in the tasks.json file.
```

My tasks.json file looks like this. This has always worked in any other Typescript project.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w"],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

It doesn't work, and even when I add 'isBuildCommand', I still get the same error!

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isBuildCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w"],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open issue with the latest version of VS Code. The workaround is to close the folder and open it again.

Related issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24796

Comment: I have the same problem since two days ago. I tried the suggestion closing and opening the folder...closing and opening visual studio code...uninstalling and installing visual studio code...the warning message still appears...and my typescript files are not transpiled...Is this a bug in the version 1.11.2? (that's the version installed  in my pc - windows 8.1)